# How to find changes concerning one particular data structure?

Tags: git

I'm browsing a git repository.
Say I have a data structure in a file cache.h:

```
struct cache_entry {
    struct cache_time ctime;
    struct cache_time mtime;
    unsigned int st_dev;
    unsigned int st_ino;
    unsigned int st_mode;
    unsigned int st_uid;
    unsigned int st_gid;
    unsigned int st_size;
    unsigned char sha1[20];
    unsigned short namelen;
    unsigned char name[0];
};
```

How can I find all subsequent versions which contain changes on this particular data structure ?

For example, after 20 commits, the author added a new entry in the above data structure.

So basically I want to see the evolution of code on a particular data structure.

Is this possible in Git ?

Comment: finding changes isn't hard, just use bash (or other shell commands) and loop through each commit (using HEAD, HEAD~1, HEAD~2), and do a git diff on that file. Only hard part is how to display changes found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git pickaxe may do want you want - for example if you wanted to find every change related to `st_mode`

```
git log -Sst_mode
```

Basically it is a grep string as git returns any commit it finds that contains that string.

git blame may also help. This will show last commits for lines 100 to 125 in filename

```
git blame -L100,125 filename
```

Comment: Well I've tried this on my example and it DID find the right commits but also includes some commits not containing what i want

Comment: Those commits must have referenced the string - including in the commit message. Try `git show <commit-id>` to see if you can find why

Comment: It did. I guess we can't do better than this. It would take more intelligence than simply string grepping. Thanks man

Comment: `git bisect` can also help you locate a particular change. It is a little more labor intensive.